# Webpack does not recognizing react component

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am getting following error while trying to build using webpack

```
ERROR in ./packages/chat/index.js 12:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (12:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| console.log('start rendering chat');
| ReactDOM.render(
>   <div>
|     <Provider store={globalStore}>
|       <ChatUi />
```

FILE -->  webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const appPath = suffix => path.resolve(__dirname, suffix);
const entries = { chat: appPath('../packages/chat/index.js') };
module.exports = {
  name: 'Library',
  entry: entries,
  output: {
    path: appPath('../dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    filename: '[name]/index.js'
  },
  mode: 'production',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /[\.js|\.jsx]$/, /* only load js and jsx files and ignore non js files */
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude:path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './packages')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }]
  }
};
```

FILE -->  .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
}
```

FILE --> index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ChatUi from '../../src/chatUi/ChatUi';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {globalStore} from '../../src/common/load-redux';

console.log('start rendering chat');
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={globalStore}>
      <ChatUi />
    </Provider>,
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('chat')
);
```

Already spent almost a whole day going through similar questions on stack overflow with no success. Getting frustrated now... :(

Comment: what is the version of your webpack?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
  <Provider store={globalStore}>
    <ChatUi />
  </Provider>,   <----- there is your problem
</div>,
```

**Update**

Check your presets. Not sure if `react` in there is just an alias for `@babel/preset-react` or if you placed the react framework lib there by accident.

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
}
```

should read

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "@babel/preset-react", "stage-0"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer buddy, but the issue is still there even after removing this.

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha Did my second approach about the `presets` fix your issue?

Comment: No @Martin, It did not. :(

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha Does it make a difference if you wrap your outer `<div>` with a `<React.Fragment>`? Or if you move your JSX into a quick functional component and just put `<MyQuickFuncComp />` into the `reactDOM.render()`?